# PHP use session vars in class functions

Tags: php, jquery, function, session

G'day All,

So, I am using jQuery File Upload, and I have it working fine, except for the upload destination, I can set a static path no worres and it works fine, however, I am trying to set the folder path dynamically using a session variable, and I can not seem to get it working, I have been trying for 2 days and can't figure it out...

I found this code for returning the session var if found (note I have changed the false return to '32/Docs/' to give me a false positive check to play with...)

```
public function getDocsULDIR($DocsULDIRkey)
{
    return (isset($_SESSION[$DocsULDIRkey])) ? $_SESSION[$DocsULDIRkey] : '32/Docs/';
}
```

The function seems to work in the `UploadHandler.php` file, as it uploads files to the false positive no worries:

```
'upload_dir' => dirname($this->get_server_var('SCRIPT_FILENAME')).'/'.$this->getDocsULDIR('DBPrimaryKeyRef').'',
'upload_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/'.$this->getDocsULDIR('DBPrimaryKeyRef').'',
```

So it appears the `isset($_SESSION[$DocsULDIRkey])` statement is faulty...

Now, this has me stumped, as I call it via an echo in the code prior to calling the jQuery file upload script and it displays as expected, showing the session variable to be set...

Can anyone please tell me why the public function `getDocsULDIR($DocsULDIRkey)` does not detect the session variable `$_SESSION['DBPrimaryKeyRef']`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you started session : `session_start()`?

Comment: Did you set the value for **$_SESSION['DBPrimaryKeyRef']**?

Comment: the site is a multi userlevel site that uses $_session values throughout

so yes, the session_start() has been called, and $_SESSION['DBPrimaryKeyRef'] has been set, and returns perfectly elsewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the input people, turns out I had to call the session insode a protected function referenced within the uploader :)

```
protected function get_DIR_id() {
    @session_start();
    return $_SESSION["DocsULPrimKey"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, break your problem apart:

1 - try uploading it to a static directory, like /tmp which has write permissions for everyone so you won't get any problems there

2 - tackle your database and session issues, make sure on every upload that your session data is properly set by returning a json to your ajax upload (json_encode($_SESSION)) and make sure all your required variables are there.

3 - make the glue by using your session variables the upload path

just to be sure, I'm seeing you use $_SERVER and $_SESSION vars there but uploads go through $_FILES, are you using it?

Comment: easy way to debug your session and be sure all that has to be there is, like DocsULDIRkey